# Tutorial and usage samples on PharoVMBuilder

Tags: interpreter, smalltalk, pharo

How can I use Pharo VM for my own programming language realization ?
Where can I found tutorial on Slang and/or making my own .image from scratch ?

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, in Smalltalk you don't build a `.image` from scratch. What you do instead is to build your own programming language inside an existent Smalltalk dialect until you get something that is able to run independently. One example of this is [Newspeak](http://newspeaklanguage.org). Another is [Cuis](http://www.jvuletich.org/Cuis/Index.html). Also, [Pharo](http://pharo.org) itself took that pathway when it forked from [Squeak](http://squeak.org).

Of course, all these are major projects. If your motivation is to provide your own syntax and programming rules (e.g., type declaration, etc.), then you don't need to build a full `.image` from scratch but to build your language (`Compiler` and UI) inside Pharo, which in any case would be the way to go.

Comment: Making interpreter in large system It's only first step and this step is clear. But question was about next step: "disconnecting" working hosted interpreter from base system, as it described in "back to the feature" article. I see lot of notes on slang\vmmaker, this bundle looks like ready to use tool for making this second step.

Comment: And I take in mind other thing - I want to test slang as crosstranslator for tiny microcontrollers with few Kb of  flash/ram. Debugging code (not hardwired with mcu hardware) in full smalltalk system looks attractive.

Comment: @DmitryPonyatov  I don't understand what looks attractive to you in Smalltalk, because you want to use Slang to generate C for microcontrollers. And the Slang part is something where you cannot use almost anything of the full Smalltalk system, live programming nor the majority of the tools. Slang is useful only to produce C code from a subset of Smalltalk.

Answer (score 1):

Some intros on lowlevel compiling in SmallTalk:

http://www.mirandabanda.org/cogblog/2011/03/01/build-me-a-jit-as-fast-as-you-can/

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own language using things like Helvetia. https://github.com/UMMISCO/Helvetia

For CLI support, there are command line handlers that can deliver something like the Scale DSL https://github.com/guillep/Scale

Moose provides support for doing something like https://ummisco.github.io/kendrick/

Now, I understand you may be looking for Slang, which is actually the code generator bit of VMMaker. This is available as a single package at http://www.smalltalkhub.com/#!/~PavelKrivanek/CCodeGenerator

I think that you can get this adjusted to use whatever compiler.